# Extract and add email address from url into form field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, email, url, extract

I am trying to extract an email address from the URL into an html form's email input field.

```
<form method='post' action='someaction'>
<input type='text' id='email_address' name='email_address' value=''>

<script>
var mail = document.querySelector('input#email_address');
if (mail) {
var t = document.location.href.split('?')[1];
if (t) {
    var params = {};
    var lst = t.split('&'), l = lst.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        var p = lst[i].split('=');
        if (!p[1]) continue;
        params[p[0]] = p[1];
    }

    if (params.mail) {
        mail.value = params.mail;
    }
    }
    }

</script>


<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

This **IS** working on my local machine when I add a ?mail=sample@emailid.com, the email address gets pre-populated in the email input field... but when I move it to my wordpress site, nothing happens. No error in the console, nothing.

What could be going wrong in the live version?

Answer (score 0):

Try hosting the site yourself, with either apache or nginx.

Comment: I think the second array value is on purpose.  He's getting the query string at the end of the URL.  That would be the second array value, because he used the `split()` method.

Comment: Exactly, and like I said, it's working on my local PC, but when i shift it to the site, literally nothing happens... is there any other way I could tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue... apparently, since I was using the code on a wordpress site, wordpress was converting & into &%30 kind of utf-8 format...

So instead of inline, I am calling the script from another location, works perfectly now...